# Why does 2023 MacBook Pro 14" change brightness upon waking from sleep?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake

I have a brand-new 14" MacBook Pro M2 running Ventura 13.2.1. In System Preferences ▹ Displays, I have "Automatically adjust brightness" turned **off**. I'm *not* using an external monitor. I set the brightness to full when using the laptop. When the laptop wakes from sleep, the brightness is down to half, not the full brightness I used before it went to sleep. This is 100% reproducible. I don't have to close the lid; simply letting it time out and put the display to sleep makes this happen.

Why is this happening, and how can I make it stop, so that I don't have to keep resetting the brightness up every time I wake the machine from sleep?

Comment: This seems to be confirmation of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/457336/how-to-stop-mac-from-dimming-after-waking-up-from-sleep - though it has no answer or even comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant setting turns out to concern the behavior when running on battery power. To stop the behavior I was seeing, go to the Displays panel of System Preferences, then click on the **Advanced …** button at the bottom,

[image]

and in the sheet that is shown next, turn *off* the setting titled "Slightly dim the display on battery":

[image]

Comment: For Sonoma this setting is in battery.

Comment: Thank you SO much!! This was driving me batty on my 2019 16" MacBook Pro running macOS Ventura 13.6.1!! It was always just kind of an irritant... finally this morning I'd had enough, and found your post! Exactly what I was looking for :)